# Execute JavaScript when partial is rendered?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two partials, one called _contents.html.erb, which loads in some tags for D3.js, and another, _show.js.erb, which loads in JavaScript to interact with the tags in _contents. However, JavaScript only executes on a page load, so I'm not sure how to get the JavaScript to execute when it's injected.

Here is show.js.erb, where the partials are called:

```
$("body").append( "<%=j render :partial => 'contents', :locals => {:folder => @folder } %>" );
$("#jscripts").append("<%=j render :partial => 'show', formats: :js, :locals => {:folder => @folder} %>");
```

Here is _show.js.erb:

```
var data;
d3.json("/folders/<%= @folder.id %>.json"), function(error, json) {

if (error) return console.warn(error);

data = json;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
folderChildren = [],
circle;

var submissions = data.submissions;


for(submission in submissions) {
    var submissionWords = submission.content.split(' ').join('');
    var size = submissionWords.length;
    folderChildren.push(size);
};

circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data(folderChildren)
 .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("cy", 90)
     .attr("cx", String)
     .attr("r", Math.sqrt);

circle.exit().remove();
```

};

The second line injects the JS partial, and when I check in my Chrome Developer Console it does successfully inject it with the rest of my JavaScript. Now, how do I get it to execute?

Comment: You will have to expose a function(s) in your js file (the one included within the #jscripts block) to the global namespace and then proceed to call it out in show.js.erb.  Exposing to global namespace is less than ideal but I couldn't think of another way when working on my own projects

Answer (score 0):

In your `show.js` you can remove the secound line and replace it whith the render command only like this:

```
<%=j render :partial => 'show', formats: :js, :locals => {:folder => @folder} %>
```

The append method appends html to a page but when you append js its not executed because js is only parsed once when you load the page so the append method ios not an appropriate solution for your problem.

Comment: Whats your problem with the solution I posted? Does it not work for your needs?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question the OP posted, he needs to execute a piece of js after he renders with rails_ujs